# 'View in Browser' with Razor and MVC in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I'm currently playing with Razor and MVC in VS 2017, but, unlike aspx pages, I can't simply view in browser to see what it looks like when rendered, instead I have to copy it to the host and view it live on the internet.

Is there a way to view in browser without publishing it remotely?

Thanks

Comment: you can just hit the play button in visual studio and run the project locally. you don't need to publish anything to run a project.

Comment: Check this, It might help you with your question. [Can CSHTML files run directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424368/can-cshtml-files-run-directly)

Comment: I can't see a play button. Do I need to set up a local IIS?

Comment: Re-run the [Visual Studio installer](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) and check if the **ASP.NET and web development** workload has been installed (if not, *do so*). And in tab "Individual components" of the same installer, check if **IIS Express** has been installed (if not, *do so*).

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, from the main menu select:

View -> Toolbars -> Standard (Make sure Standard is checked)

Just below the main menu, you should see a row, or many rows, of icons. You want to look for a green arrow icon. After locating the green arrow and clicking on it, Visual Studio will attempt to first build your project, which if successful, will then proceed to run your project in localhost. If it doesn't build you will be notified and you can review the Error List tab at the bottom of Visual Studio as to the reasons why.

After a successful build, Visual Studio will open your default browser automatically and redirect itself to the localhost and port number of where your application is running. You should now see your application running. It will have a url in the browser something similar to the following https://localhost:5000/

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I did as you suggested but was given an error page "Server Error in '/' Application.

The network path was not found "

Comment: My initial thought is if your application has a database connected, try confirming that the connection string for the database is correct.